# How to show modal popup when I select future or past dates in jQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to show modal popup when I select future and past dates in `jQuery` datepicker. I am using v1.12.1 datepicker and `jQuery` v3.3.1

I found one way on internet but that is not a latest version of `jQuery`. So it's not working for me..

Example fiddle here

**[Here is my Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/koj8vaue/)**

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

$("#datepicker").change(function(){
     var date = $(this).val();
    $('<div>' + date + '</div>').dialog();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

> **Note:** Modal popup like, "You are select future dates, do you want to continue? yes or No." like that.

Comment: have you tried bootstrap modal ?

Comment: please refere link for more info.https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: yess, but i dont know how to inistilize bootstrap modal in jQuery datepicker

Comment: which library is used for date picker? from above example it seems look like that you have to add datepicker jquery library first

Comment: yess, im using jquery datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code it will be work.

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" integrity="sha256-n3ci71vDbbK59GUg1tuo+c3KO7+pnBOzt7BDmOe87s4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js" integrity="sha256-KgOC04qt96w+EFba7KuNt9sT+ahJua25I0I2rrkZHFo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker">
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker().on("change", function (e) {
                var today = new Date();
                var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (today.getDate()) + "/" + (today.getFullYear());
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                if ($(this).val() == date) {
                    $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected today");
                } else if ($(this).val() < date) {
                    $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected past date");
                } else {
                    $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected future date");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you bro. and how can i apply IF condition for select past date and future date??

Comment: hii.. i have small doubt.. if i select a date for next month 8th (8/12/2019), it shown past date.. why? next month is future date na..! why ist shown past date??

Comment: As per above my answer "8/12/2019" 8 is consider as month I have used MM-DD-YYYY format

Comment: Im using like that `var date = (today.getDate()) + "/" + (today.getMonth()) + "/" + (today.getFullYear());` but still that problem is came.. if i select Next month 1 to 10 dates, its shown past date..

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use plain java-script modal popup to show your output.

```
<div id="datepicker" style="font: 80% 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;"></div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="body">Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();

$("#datepicker").change(function(){
     var date = $(this).val();
     $("#body").html("You have selected future date:"+ date);
     modal.style.display = "block";
});

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];



// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function isFutureDate(idate){
var today = new Date().getTime();
idate = new Date(idate).getTime();
return (today - idate) < 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/xe2kr6bv/9/)

Comment: Thankyou so much for given idea sir, and its not working for jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: its working but your Jquery is overlapping because datepicker is using old js and you are using new js also.

Comment: its plain javascript so it will work, please check fiddle also. there is some css related to it

Comment: its perfect, working perfectly bro, can you tell me how can i write IF condition for select past date and future date?? example, if i select past date the popup will shown this is past date do you want to cont!!?, or if i select future date, the popup say you are select future date do uyou want to cont? like that??

Comment: i have small doubt.. if i select a date for next month 8th (8/12/2019), it shown past date.. why? next month is future date na..! why ist shown past date??

Comment: how can i change date format 11/20/2019 to 20/11/2019? because my case its showing wrong message.. if i select future date its showing "you are selected past date".. i think date format is problem

Comment: @joe there is moment.js file so you can format your date accordingly. and this post is regarding  your future and past date issue.

Comment: yess!! i changed the date format bro! but still that problem is came.. if i select future date its showing "you are selected past date".. please refer my code and problem - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/6nfy7cts/